# How do I reduce the space between my menu titles and items?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'd like to reduce the huge space between the menu name (ie. Menu I) and the associated menu items (ie. Biography, Publications).
What is causing the extra space and how can I reduce it?
Here is a jsfiddle link: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/VunKD/)
Many thanks

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="logo">My Name</div>
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h5>Menu I</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a title="" href="">Biography</a></li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Publications</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li>
      <h5>Menu 2</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><a title="" href="">Demo</a></li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Features</a></li>
        <li><a title="" href="">Comparison</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="intro-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut.</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    background-color: #005EBC;
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 35px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#intro-text {
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 20px;
    font-size:12px;
}

/* mainmenu */

H5 {
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#mainmenu {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: -40px;
    *padding-top: -40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mainmenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: right;
    color: #C3C;
}

#mainmenu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#mainmenu>ul>li { margin-left: 20px }

#mainmenu ul li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
}

#mainmenu ul li a,
#mainmenu ul ul:hover li a { color: green }


#mainmenu ul ul li a:hover,
#mainmenu ul ul li.current-menu-item a { color: red }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using a `<h5>` tag which come default with hefty top and bottom margins.

```
h5 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQVtN/)